# How to fix a credential authentication in SAP BW connecte to Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, sap-bw

I was using a personal gateway to update a report every day, but once I came across a series of errors due to not keeping my machine on all the time, I was no longer able to update my credentials. I am using a connection to Sap BW for an organizational database, the same server works on the desktop version.

I tried to change my password to the SAP BW server some times and change to a new personal gateway, isn't worked too.